# SignalR Core Missing 'Connection' header on IIS

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, iis, signalr, iis-10

I'm having problems with a SignalR-based application. For some reason, it works on one deployment target, but not another. It fails to connect via WebSockets and reverts back to LongPolling.

The code is the same, and they are both hosting an ASP.NET Core app in IIS 10 on Windows Server 2016.

What happens is that the client will throw an exception due to a missing 'Connection: Upgrade' header. When I compare the two responses (after auth), I see the following in Fiddlr:

GOOD

```
GET http://api.example.com/signalr/engineClientHub?id=-AwWg63GB_YLXjT9G55c3Q HTTP/1.1
Upgrade: websocket
Sec-WebSocket-Key: <SIC>
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Authorization: Negotiate <SIC>
Host: api.example.com
Connection: Upgrade

HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Persistent-Auth: false
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: <SIC>
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Powered-By: ARR/3.0
Connection: Upgrade            <-- I want this
Date: Wed, 13 May 2020 08:57:24 GMT
EndTime: 10:57:34.797
ReceivedBytes: 437142
SentBytes: 722
```

BAD

```
GET http://apitest.example.com/signalr/engineClientHub?id=Quhez1nVLaqH2h4POKr1pg HTTP/1.1
Upgrade: websocket
Sec-WebSocket-Key: <SIC>
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Authorization: Negotiate <SIC>
Host: apitest.example.com
Connection: Upgrade

HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Transfer-Encoding: chunked      <-- But I get this
Upgrade: websocket
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Persistent-Auth: false
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: <SIC>
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Powered-By: ARR/3.0
Date: Wed, 13 May 2020 08:34:06 GMT
EndTime: 10:34:06.179
ReceivedBytes: 5
SentBytes: 0
```

Does anyone have any clue why one response is chunked and missing the header while the other is OK? We did nothing except install WebSocket support on both servers as far as I am aware.

Comment: first, make sure you configure WebSocket correctly with iis, not https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-3.1. is your transferred data is too large? Transfer-Encoding: chunked - there is no content-length specified, the server tells us it will send a bunch of chunks whenever it has data, and when the response is done it will tell us by closing the connection.you could try failed request tracing  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: @JalpaPanchal Thanks. I'm actually a bit puzzled by how this works in terms of chunked transfer. I wouldn't expect the upgrade response to actually contain any data. I tried failed request tracing, but I'm not sure whether the server sees this as a failed response. It's the client that throws an exception due to the missing header.

Comment: try to run the failed request tracing in iis for the 101 status code and find what is happening in iis.

Comment: My issue was indeed a WebSocket configuration, but not on the server hosting the API. We had a reverse proxy where it also needed to be enabled. 2 days of problems, 5 seconds to fix :D